# Creating subdomain in amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subdomain, bitnami

I have the instance ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com. It is running a bitnami lamp stack. 
How do I create a subdomain for this like subDomain.ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com? 
Is it possible to do such this or should I purchase a domain first? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot manage AWS domains. You need to have your own domain first and use Route 53 or any other DNS provider to create an A record pointing to this specific EC2 instance.

Before creating the A record however you will need to provision an Elastic IP and assign it to your EC2. Please keep in mind that every account starts out with only 5 Elastic IPs and if you need more you will have to get in touch with Amazon for approval.

Comment: I was afraid this would not be possible. Thanks for confirming!